# "<<" inserts a pointer to a variable when I try to append the value of this variable, to another variable. How do I avoid this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for the messy title.

If I use static values (rails console):

```
 2.1.2 :013 > h=[]
  => [] 
 2.1.2 :014 > h<<[1]
  => [[1]] 
 2.1.2 :015 > h<<[1,2]
  => [[1], [1, 2]] 
 2.1.2 :016 > h<<[1,2,3]
  => [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

It works as expected. Same if I use a variable that uses static values, like this:

```
 2.1.2 :018 > h=[]
  => [] 
 2.1.2 :019 > a=1
  => 1 
 2.1.2 :020 > h<<a
  => [1] 
 2.1.2 :021 > a=[1,2]
  => [1, 2] 
 2.1.2 :022 > h<<a   
  => [1, [1, 2]] 
 2.1.2 :023 > a=[1,2,3]
  => [1, 2, 3] 
 2.1.2 :024 > h<<a
  => [1, [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

But if I do the following, the values of the variable are replaced onto the entire array, like it was a pointer:

```
 2.1.2 :036 > h=[]
  => [] 
 2.1.2 :037 > a=[]
  => [] 
 2.1.2 :038 > a<<1
  => [1] 
 2.1.2 :039 > h<<a
  => [[1]] 
 2.1.2 :040 > a<<2
  => [1, 2] 
 2.1.2 :041 > h<<a
  => [[1, 2], [1, 2]] 
 2.1.2 :042 > a<<3
  => [1, 2, 3] 
 2.1.2 :043 > h<<a
  => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Notice how all the values of h get replaced by the new value of a.The same happens if I use "h.append(X)". If I use another variable, the values don't get replaced:

```
 2.1.2 :044 > b=[1,2,3]
  => [1, 2, 3] 
 2.1.2 :045 > b<<4
  => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
 2.1.2 :046 > h<<b
  => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I've temporary solved this by using something like "h << a.to_s", but that converts the numerical values to strings, which causes problems when I need to do math with them. Another alternative I ran into is by using "h << a.inspect", except the values get encased by quotes like this:

```
 ["[1]", "[1,2]", "[1,2,3]"]
```

which is ok'ish, but the quotes cause other problems as well. Ideally, I'd want them like this:

```
 [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Or perhaps, using a different way to insert the arrays into a hash/array/json variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can duplicate the reference before inserting into the array:

```
> h = []
> a = []
> a << 1
> h << a.dup
> a << 2
> h << a.dup
> a << 3
> h << a.dup
> h
# => [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that Ruby effectively passes parameters *by reference*¹ – only basic types like floats, ints, true, false and nil are immutable and thus will not expose the behaviour you observed. For all other objects, one possible workaround is to use `dup`:

```
h = []
a = []
a = a.dup << 1 #=> [1]
h << a         #=> [[1]]
a = a.dup << 2 #=> [1, 2]
h << a         #=> [[1], [1, 2]]
a = a.dup << 3 #=> [1, 2, 3]
h << a         #=> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
h              #=> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Another way is to make use of `+=`, which implicitly returns a copy. However, the right hand argument then must be an array instead of a single value:

```
h = []
a = []
a += [1] #=> [1]
h << a   #=> [[1]]
a += [2] #=> [1, 2]
h << a   #=> [[1], [1, 2]]
a += [3] #=> [1, 2, 3]
h << a   #=> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
h        #=> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

¹Although internally, Ruby passes them by value, but these values are references

Comment: That helps understanding what's going on, thanks. I was quite confused cause I always assumed it'd be the value, not the reference.

Comment: Ruby is pass-by-value (although the passed values are always references). The "simple types" you refer to are in fact immutable values, i.e. objects which can't be changed. These include `Fixnum`, `Float`, `true`, `false`, `nil`). Strings however are *not* immutable as `str = "Hello"; a << " World"` changes the original string. Still, all objects are referred to by their reference, including Fixnums and Floats.

Comment: Finally, you can't use `+=` on `h` for the desired result. The pasted code does not work and produces different result from the ones suggested by the comments.

Comment: @HolgerJust very useful additions, thanks. Edited my answer to reflect these aspects. The code copied from the now deleted answer was indeed incorrect, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get object id for variable 'a' by Object#object_id， it can help you understand.

```
irb(main):060:0> a= 1
=> 1
irb(main):061:0> a.object_id
=> 3
irb(main):062:0> a= [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):063:0> a.object_id
=> 20017440
irb(main):064:0> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):065:0> a.object_id
=> 19627820
```

The object_id of variable a is different.

```
irb(main):066:0> a= []
=> []
irb(main):067:0> a << 1
=> [1]
irb(main):068:0> a.object_id
=> 18718920
irb(main):069:0> a << 2
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):070:0> a.object_id
=> 18718920
irb(main):071:0> a << 3
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):072:0> a.object_id
=> 18718920
```

If you use "<<", the object_id of variable 'a' will not change, if you change the value of variable a, all elements of array 'h' will change.

So you can use 'a.dup' get a shallow copy of object a, then add it to array h.